# How to get the date selected in input type=date in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I have an HTML code like this one:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
    <input type="date">
</form>
```

I want to have an event or something that will check when the date is changed, and get the date in JS Date object?

Answer (score 6):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K3aK8/1/)**

Try [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler on the `input`,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="date"]').change(function(){
        alert(this.value);         //Date in full format alert(new Date(this.value));
        var inputDate = new Date(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `this[0].value ?` for me the jQuery selector returns an array

Comment: @user3206440, no. `this` is just one context : the input that has currently changed. So it will never return an array in `this`.

Comment: ok, makes sense.  if we simply use `$('input[type="date"]')` that gives an array.

Comment: FYI: These events will fire with a blank value if the keyboard is used to select a date that is not valid. ie. Feb 30.

Answer (score 4):

Attach the `change` event handler and convert the value into `Date`:

```
$("input").on("change", function () {
    var myDate = new Date($(this).val());
    console.log(myDate, myDate.getTime());
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6fMu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a .change() jquery handler it will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#dateInput').change(function(){
       console.log('Updated Date');
  });
});

<form>
   <input id="dateInput" type="date" />
</form>
```